# JUNIT not runnig

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Intellij IDEA and junit testing. Right now I am writting a quicksort code and writting tests for the classes. When I try to run the test they turn grey and does not go through. How should I fix this?

Down under I have included Test classes and the classes for Quicksort.

// TODO: Help me Understand how to fix the testclasses so the test goes through.

Please be kind, I am new to JUNIT testing.

Here is my codes:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

public class QuicksortFixedPivotTest extends IntSorterTest{
    /**
     * Returns an implementation of the IntSorter interface. Extending classes
     * must override this method.
     *
     * @return An implementation of IntSorter.
     */
    /* An instance of the quicksortFixedPivot */
    private QuicksortFixedPivot quicksortFixedPivot;

    private InsertionSort quickSort;


    /* An array of even length */
    private int[] evenArray;
    /* An array of odd length */
    private int[] oddArray;
    private Random random;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
       quicksortFixedPivot = new QuicksortFixedPivot();

        evenArray = new int[]{1,5,3,8};
        oddArray = new int[]{1,5,2,4,3};
    }


    /**
     * Returns an implementation of the IntSorter interface. Extending classes
     * must override this method.
     *
     * @return An implementation of IntSorter.
     */
    @Override
    protected IntSorter getIntSorter() {
        return new IntSorter() {
            @Override
            public void sort(int[] v) {
                Arrays.sort(v);
            }
        };
    }

    //TESTs for arrays of even and odd length
  @Test
   public void QuickSortFindsAllElementsInEvenArray() {
       // Arrange
       Arrays.sort(evenArray);
      String result = new String();
       for (int i = 0; i > evenArray.length; i++) {
           result = result + " " + evenArray[i];
           // Act, Assert
           assertEquals("1 3 5 8", result);
           assertThat(evenArray.length,equalTo(i));
       }
   }



    /**
     * Test of generateBigArray method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGenerateBigArray() throws IOException {
        int n = 1000;
        InsertionSort i = new InsertionSort();
        int[] expResult = i.generateBigArray(n);
        int[] result = expResult;
        assertArrayEquals(expResult, result);
    }


    /**
     * Assert that binarySearch returns the correct index
     * for all elements in an odd length array with multiple elements.
     */
    @Test
    public void QuickSortFindsAllElementsInOddArray() {
        //arrange
        Arrays.sort(oddArray);
        String result = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i > oddArray.length; i++) {
            result = result + " " + oddArray[i];
            // Act, Assert
            assertEquals(" 1 2 3 4 5", result);
            assertThat(oddArray.length, equalTo(i));

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int[] list = {};
        String result = new String();
        quicksortFixedPivot.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            result = result + " " + list[i];
        assertEquals("", result);
    }
}
```

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

 import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

/**
  * Abstract test class for  implementations.
  *
  * Implementing test classes must override the getIntSorter method.
  */
 public abstract class IntSorterTest {
     private Data data;
     private InsertionSort sorter;

     int [] emptyArray = new int[] {}; // An empty array

    /* An array of even length */
    private int[] evenArray;
    /* An array of odd length */
    private int[] oddArray;

    private Random random;
    /**
     /**
      * Returns an implementation of the IntSorter interface. Extending classes
      * must override this method.
      *
      * @return An implementation of IntSorter.
      */
     protected abstract IntSorter getIntSorter();

    @Before
     public void setUp() throws IOException {
        sorter = new InsertionSort();
        evenArray = new int[]{1,5,3,8};
        oddArray = new int[]{1,5,2,4,3};
     }

    /**
     * Assert that the size of an empty Array is exactly 0.
     */
    @Test
    public void sizeIsZeroWhenArrayIsEmpty() {
        int size = emptyArray.length;
        assertThat(size,equalTo(0));
        assertTrue(emptyArray.length == 0);
    }
    /**
     * Assert that sorting an empty array has no effects.
     */
    @Test
    public void sortHasNoEffectWhenArrayIsEmpty() {
        // Arrange
        int [] emptyArray = new int[] {};
        // Act
        Arrays.sort(emptyArray);
        // Assert
        assertThat(emptyArray.length, equalTo(0));
    }


    /**
     * Assert that sorting an array with a single element has no effects.
     */
    @Test
    public void sortHasNoEffectWhenArrayHasSingleElement() {
        //Arrange
        int[] array = new int[1];
        //act
        Arrays.sort(array);
        //assert
        assertThat(array.length,equalTo(1));
    }

    /**
     * Assert that arrayA is the reverse of arrayB.
     */
    @Test
    public void assertReversed() {
        int [] arrayA = {1, 3, 4};
        int [] arrayB = {4, 3, 1};
        Integer len = arrayA.length;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            assertThat(arrayB[len-i-1], equalTo(arrayA[i]));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that sorting a multiple element array results in a correct
     * ordering of the elements.
     */
    @Test
    public void sortMultipleElementArrayGivesCorrectOrdering() {
        // Arrange
        int[] actual = evenArray;
        int[] expected = actual.clone();
        // Act
        Arrays.sort(expected);
        Arrays.sort(actual);
        // Assert
        assertThat(actual, equalTo(expected));
    }

    /**
     *   Test case number: 5
     *   Pre-condition: given integer list {1,2,3 }
     *   Test case values: call quickSort to sort it
     *   Expected output (Post-state): "1 2 3"
     */
    @Test
    public void test5() {
        int[] list = { 1, 2, 3 };
        String result = new String();
        sorter.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            result = result + " " + list[i];
        assertEquals(" 1 2 3", result);
    }

    /**
     * Test sorting a negative array.
     */
    @Test
    public void NegativeArray() {
        int[] list = { -1, 2, -3 };
        String result = new String();
        sorter.sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            result = result + " " + list[i];
        assertEquals(" -3 -1 2", result);
    }



    /**
     * Sorting a reverse sorted array.
     */
    @Test
    public void testReverseSorted() {
        int[] array1 = new int[10];
        int[] array2 = new int[10];

        int[] array3 = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array1[i] = (100-i);
            array2[i] = (100-i);
            array3[i] = (100-i);
        }
        //sort array3
        Arrays.sort(array3);
        // run QS1()
        sorter.sort(array1);
        assertArrayEquals(array1,array3);

        // run QS2()
        sorter.sort(array2);
        assertArrayEquals(array2,array3);
    }




    /**
     * Test that all elements are equal in two different arrays
     * when sorted. Ascending order
     */
    @Test
     public void testSort() {
         int[] array = {0, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 11, 100, 2};
         sorter.sort(array);
         int[] expected = {0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 100};
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
         assertEquals(true, Arrays.equals(expected, array));
     }

     @Test
     public void testSort2() {
         int[] array = {0, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 11, 100, 2};
         sorter.sort(array);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
         assertEquals(true, isSorted(array));
     }

    /**
     * helper method for tests that is in ascending order.
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
     private boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
         boolean sorted = true;
         for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
             sorted = sorted && array[i] <= array[i+1];
             if(!sorted) {
                 System.out.println(array[i] +" >" +array[i+1]);
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return sorted;
     }

 }
```

```
/**
 * An interface for sorting int arrays.
 */
public interface IntSorter {
    /**
     * Sorts the array in-place into ascending numerical order.
     *
     * @param v An array of ints.
     */
    void sort(int[] v);
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class QuicksortFixedPivot implements IntSorter{
    /**
     * Sorts the array in-place into ascending numerical order.
     *
     * @param v An array of ints.
     */
    @Override
    public void sort(int[] v) {
        if (v != null && v.length > 1)
            qsort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
    }
    public void qsort(int[] v, int start, int end) {
        if(start < end) {
            int[] mid = partition(v, start, end);
            qsort(v, start, mid[0] - 1);
            qsort(v, mid[1] + 1, end);
        }
    }

    public int[] partition(int[] v, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = v[choosePivot(v, start, end)];
        int low = start, mid = start, high = end;
        while (mid <= high) {
            if (v[mid] < pivot) {
                swap(v, mid, low);
                low++;
                mid++;
            } else if (v[mid] == pivot) {
                mid++;
            } else {
                swap(v, mid, high);
                high--;
            }
        }
        return new int[]{low, high};
    }

    public int choosePivot(int[] v, int start, int end) {
        return start + (end - start)/2;
    }

    public void swap(int[] v, int i, int j) {
        if(i == j) return;
        int t = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = t;
    }
    public QuicksortFixedPivot() throws IOException {
        Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);
        int n = io.getInt(); // number of elements to sort
        int[] v = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        // read in problem array
        while (io.hasMoreTokens()) {
            v[i++] = io.getInt();
        }
        sort(v);
        // output sorted array as solution
        for (int k : v) {
            io.println(k);
        }
        io.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tests turning grey can mean a lot of things.  "Tests not going through" is even less of a description of a problem that can be fixed.  Please try to find an error message that says something is wrong, because your comments amount to "it's broken" and while we agree it doesn't work, that doesn't give us enough information to know how it is broken, which means we can't recommend how to fix it, as there are thousands of things that could be fixed, but you are probably only running into one thing that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I understand that, however The problem is I don´t know what the problem is and I dont get any error to help me find the problem

Comment: Well, until you can describe the problem with more detail, as much as we would like to, we cannot help you in a meaningful way.  I would start off with some general tutorials on "running JUnit tests in IntelliJ IDEA"  Pay close attention to the version of JUnit you are using (there's the JUnit 4, JUnit 5, and Jupiter) and the version of IntelliJ IDEA.  See if you can find a beginner's guide that matches the version of JUnit and IntelliJ you are using.  While doing that, if you can find a log file or other output that contains an error, add that to this question.

Comment: This is more likely to be a project set up than a test issue. Your Junit 4 tests look like they should execute.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze with the project set up do you mean the setup method in IntSorterTest or?

Comment: It looks to me like this is an issue of how you've set up your IntelliJ project. Do ANY tests run? If not, then I suggest you create a fresh project and get some sort of unit test to work in there. Then import this code.